# (CSS / jQuery/ XPath) Selector for getting inner text from sister/sibling node (DOM)

Tags: dom, xpath, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, siblings

Get text "100" (from "100 meters", displayed by the below HTML),
**using selectors only** (CSS/jQuery and less preferred - XPath).

From the **2 sister div tags** below, identify the 2nd one (with text "meters")
and finally extract the text of the 1st one ("100"):

```
<div class="parameter">
  <div class="parameter-value"> 100 </div>
  <div class="parameter-measure-unit"> meters </div>
</div>
```

This means:

1. Uniquely identify the second **div**, with class *parameter-measure-unit*
2. Then uniquely identify **its sibling-sister div**, the first **div**, with class *parameter-value*
3. Extract the value ("100") out of this sister **div**.

Preference for CSS/jQuery selector instead of XPath.

Comment: More specific suggestions are welcomed / awaited. Don't hesitate if you fully understood the question.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector is

```
div.parameter-value
```

Or if this is not unique enough

```
parameter.parameter>div.parameter-value
```

Comment: Please revise this answer. It doesn't address the question properly.

Comment: Maybe you should revise your question? I answered according to what I understand you asking here.

Comment: Done. Your turn.

Comment: I do not understand why do you need to identify the second sibling if you will extract the text from the first sibling? Also, are class names are fixed and predefined (known)?